# Start armv7 container on arm64 with lxc / lxd

Tags: debian, arm, lxc, lxd

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Raspberry PI, which has an `arm64v8` architecture (but could be on any other debian arm distribution / hardware).

Currently I compile a program for several arm architectures / distros. So I use lxc container for that purpose. This worked well for all debian and ubuntu versions for the `arm64v8` architecture.

Then I [downloaded](https://us.images.linuxcontainers.org/) an `armhf` container for debian buster, which technically should be architecture `arm32v7` alias `armv7`:

```
lxc launch images:debian/10/armhf armhf-buster
```

Then I logged in the container and `uname -a` says: `armv8l`. I tried even to compile, but pip wheel refuses to take the `arm32v7` packages and therefore I have to compile all dependencies for `arm32v8` myself, which takes ages (waited 4 hours for one package and then aborted) due to limited memory and cpu capacaties.

**Anyways: is there a way to launch a container as `armv7` on an `arm64v8` distro?**

*P.s.: also obviously I can install the official `Raspberry PI OS`, which is `armv7l` on that `armv8` processor, so technically shouldn't be a problem to run that as lxc virtualization.*